# using 'glob' to get all images from a directory

Tags: php, file, directory, glob

I'm trying to get all images from a directory and print them.  I know my URL is correct because I am echoing the the $dirname along with a .jpg image I have saved in the directory.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  <?php

  $dirname = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/{$record_id}/";
  $images = glob($dirname . "*.jpg");
  foreach($images as $image) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
  }

  //check to see if $dirname is correct

  echo '<img src="' . $dirname . "IMG_0002.JPG" . '"/>';

  ?>
```

//edit

I have solved my problem, by removing the jpg extention and just pulling "*" for everything in the folder.  Although it works for me now, its not best practice.  It must be something to do with different .jpg file formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used lowercase file extension here.

```
$images = glob($dirname . "*.jpg");
```

And uppercase JPG in your test output.

```
  echo '<img src="' . $dirname . "IMG_0002.JPG" . '"/>';
```

If you're using a linux system then file extensions are case sensitive.

Comment: Your right, well spotted.  Although I am on a windows system, should it still matter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend the dirname to glob's result to get the full paths.

So something like:

```
$dirname = "uploads/{$site_country}_{$site_state}_{$site_name}/{$record_id}/";
$images = glob($dirname . "*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
   echo '<img src="'.$dirname.$image.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: on a sidenote, if you want to know if glob returns *anything* at all, you can do a var_dump($images) before the foreach and look in your output what was returned exactly.

Comment: my array does seem to be empty.. but my path is correct, I see if I echo ($dirname . "*.jpg") it prints the * character as a file name

Comment: I have solved my problem, by removing the jpg extention and just pulling "*" for everthing in the folder.  Although it works for me now, its not best practice.  It must be something to do with different .jpg files?